# Most concise way to select rows where any column contains a string in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

What is the most concise way to select all rows where any column contains a string in a Pandas dataframe?

For example, given the following dataframe what is the best way to select those rows where the value in any column contains a `b`?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'x': ['foo', 'foo', 'bar'],
    'y': ['foo', 'foo', 'foo'],
    'z': ['foo', 'baz', 'foo']
})
```

I'm inexperienced with Pandas and the best I've come up with so far is the rather cumbersome `df[df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('b').any(), axis=1)]`. Is there a simpler solution?

Critically, I want to check for a match in *any* columns, not a particular column. Other similar questions, as best I can tell, only address a single or list of columns.

Comment: `.str.contains` is a method defined on pd.Series so it seems one way or another you need to use apply or some kind of a loop. There might be some hacks replacing b's with NaN's and dropping based on that but your way seems clearer.

Comment: You can also do `df[df.sum(axis=1).str.contains('b')]` but I don't think that behavior is reliable. I also don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: `df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('b').any(), axis=1)]`  takes care of non-string columns, nans, etc.

Answer (score 30):

*This question was not given an answer.. but the question itself and the comments has got the answer already which worked really well for me.. and I didn't find the answer anywhereelse I looked.*

*So I just copy pasted the answer for someone who can find it useful. I added case=False for a case insensitive serach*

**Solution from @Reason:**

the best I've come up with so far is the rather cumbersome

*this one worked for me.*

```
df[df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('b', case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

**Solution from @rbinnun:**

*this one worked for me for a test dataset.. but for some real data set.. it returned a unicode error as below, but generally a good solution too I think*

`df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('b', case=False).any(), axis=1)]`

takes care of non-string columns, nans, etc.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xae' in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: If you're using Python 2, the second will try to cast the column to an ASCII string, hence the unicode error. Cast to `unicode` instead: `df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(unicode).str.contains('b', case=False).any(), axis=1)]`

Comment: This solution is super slow!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like apply:

```
df.stack()[df.stack().str.contains("b")]
```

returns

```
1  z    baz
2  x    bar
dtype: object
```

and like above with similar to original table properties:

```
df.stack()[df.stack().str.contains("b")].reset_index().pivot(index="level_0", columns="level_1").droplevel(0, 1)
```

| level_1 | x | z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NaN | baz |
| 2 | bar | NaN |

[image]