# iloc Pandas Slice Difficulties

Tags: python, pandas

Ive updated the below information to be a little clearer as per the comments:

I have the following dataframe df (it has 38 columns this is only the last few):

```
Col #   33          34          35          36          37          38
id      09.2018     10.2018     11.2018     12.2018     LTx         LTx2
123     0.505       0.505       0.505       0.505       33          35
223     2.462       2.464       0.0         30.0        33          36
323     1.231       1.231       1.231       1.231       33          35
423     0.859       0.855       0.850       0.847       33          36
```

I am trying to create a new column which is the sum of a slice using iloc so an example for col 123 it would look like the following:

```
df['LTx3'] = (df.iloc[:, 33:35]).sum(axis=1)
```

This is perfect obviously for 123 but not for 223. I had assumed this would work:

```
df['LTx3'] = (df.iloc[:, 'LTx':'LTx2']).sum(axis=1)
```

But consistantly get the same error:

```
TypeError: cannot do slice indexing on <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> with these indexers [LTx] of <class 'str'>
```

I had been trying some variation of this such as below but unfortunatley also havent led to any working solution:

```
df['LTx3'] = (df.iloc[:, df.columns.get_loc('LTx'):df.columns.get_loc('LTx2')]).sum(axis=1)
```

Basically columns LTx and LTx2 are made up of integres but vary row to row. I want to use these integers as the references for the slice - Im not quite certain how I should do this.

If anyone could help lead me to a solution it would be fantastic!

Cheers

Comment: Could you supply desired output for this particular case?

Comment: Anyway, edit your question with a desired output for this case. It’s not clear from the question what do you want to get at the end.

Comment: iloc is integer location.  You can not use strings.  Now, since your dataframe columns appear to be integers also, it may get a little confusing.  If you are using .iloc, then you are selecting the columns that are 35 integer positoin not the column labeled as 35.  In your above dataframe it only appears that you have six columns.  Therefore, if you use .iloc[0:2] to get columns labeled as [33:35].  Otherwise you need to use .loc.

Comment: Hi Ive updated my question as suggested so am hoping its clearer now for all.... Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend reading up on `.loc`, `.iloc` slicing in pandas: 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html

`.loc` selects based on name(s). `.iloc` selects based on index (numerical) position.

You can also subset based on column names. Note also that depending on how you create your dataframe, you may have numbers cast as strings.

To get the row corresponding to `223`:

```
df3 = df[df['Col'] == '223']
```

To get the columns corresponding to the *names* 33, 34, and 45:

```
df3 = df[df['Col'] == '223'].loc[:, '33':'35']
```

If you want to select rows wherein any column contains a given string, I found this solution: [Most concise way to select rows where any column contains a string in Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980514/most-concise-way-to-select-rows-where-any-column-contains-a-string-in-pandas-dat)

```
df[df.apply(lambda row: row.astype(str).str.contains('LTx2').any(), axis=1)]
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for taking the time to respond on this - Im aware that .loc is for names and .iloc is for numerical positions. Im unfortunatley still a little confused though - The reason Im trying iloc is because collumns LTx and LTx2 are supposed to be containing the actual numerical positions for the row slices (this is why the LTx2 values are changing - the slices should be different sizes) Hopefully this is a little clearer - Cheers

Comment: What do you want your output to look like? Cut and paste the rows/columns you want your code to select.

Comment: I want the output to be a new column making a sum for each row. Each rows sum though is based on a varying slice. So in the case of the first item 123 - the sum would be 1.01 (slice of 33:35) for item 423 though the sum would be 2.564 (slice of 33:36) - Cheers