# What is the fastest way to select rows that contain a value in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, string, pandas, performance

I am currently following the instructions laid out here for finding values, and it works. The only problem is my dataframe is quite big (5x3500 rows) and I need to perform around ~2000 searches. Each one takes around 4 seconds, so obviously this adds up and has become a bit unsustainable on my end.

[Most concise way to select rows where any column contains a string in Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980514/most-concise-way-to-select-rows-where-any-column-contains-a-string-in-pandas-dat?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Is there a faster way to search for all rows containing a string value than this?

```
df[df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('b', case=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can testing the speed

```
boolfilter=(np.char.find(df.values.ravel().astype(str),'b')!=-1).reshape(df.shape).any(1)
boolfilter
array([False,  True,  True])
newdf=df[boolfilter]
```

Comment: This is clever :) - just need to check lower case i think since `case=False` ?

Comment: This cut the time down into a fraction of what it was. Now to look up what's going on behind the scenes hah.

Comment: @NBC You may also want to adding the lower `(np.char.find(np.char.lower(df.values.ravel().astype(str)),'b')!=-1).reshape(df.shape).any(1)
`

Comment: thanks @Wen-Ben! Do you know of a way of tweaking this to look for exact matches as well?

Comment: @NBC `df.eq('b').any(1)`

Answer (score 2):

One trivial possibility is to disable regex:

```
res = df[df.apply(lambda r: r.str.contains('b', case=False, regex=False).any(), axis=1)]
```

Another way using a list comprehension:

```
res = df[[any('b' in x.lower() for x in row) for row in df.values)]]
```

Comment: Nice list comprehension man, would you like test the timing as well  ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben, I'd rather let OP check timing as i'm not sure how to make up random data :)