# How to add a column to dataframe checking if a string is contained in some or any columns of that row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df looks like this:

```
       food  triggered  numbers         snacks
0  sandwich      False        5           tofu
1     chips      False        2        seaweed
2       egg       True        7  yeah_whatever
3  whatever      False        1      bird food
4      milk       True       10     chia seeds

df = pd.DataFrame({'food': ['sandwich', 'chips', 'egg', 'whatever', 'milk'], 'triggered': [False, False, True, False, True], 'numbers' : [5, 2, 7, 1, 10], 'snacks': ['tofu', 'seaweed', 'yeah_whatever', 'bird food', 'chia seeds']})
```

and I want to add columns `has_food_whatevers` and `has_any_whatevers` checking if the string 'whatever' is contained (eg. 'yeah_whatever') in a range of columns or any columns of that row, to get:

```
       food  triggered  numbers         snacks  has_food_whatevers  has_any_whatevers
0  sandwich      False        5           tofu               False              False
1     chips      False        2        seaweed               False              False
2       egg       True        7  yeah_whatever               False               True
3  whatever      False        1      bird food                True               True
4      milk       True       10     chia seeds               False              False
    
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'food': ['sandwich', 'chips', 'egg', 'whatever', 'milk'], 'triggered': [False, False, True, False, True], 'numbers' : [5, 2, 7, 1, 10], 'snacks': ['tofu', 'seaweed', 'yeah_whatever', 'bird food', 'chia seeds'], 'has_food_whatevers': [False, False, False, True, False], 'has_any_whatevers': [False, False, True, True, False]})
```

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38980514/most-concise-way-to-select-rows-where-any-column-contains-a-string-in-pandas-dat) shows how to select and drop relevant rows but I don't know how to add this as a column. Can I do this with `.transform` somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Let us try `str.contains`

```
df['has_food_whatevers'] = df['food'].str.contains('whatever')
df['has_any_whatevers'] = df[['food','snacks']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('whatever')).any(1)
```

Comment: Beautiful! Can this be modified to select all columns (not only 'food' and 'snacks')?

Comment: @ChrisDixon you need to make sure you pass the str , but we can df.astye(str).apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('whatever')).any(1)